# SASS, Rails 7: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I've faced a problem: when I want to import to my main stylesheet a library that I've installed via yarn I received an error that probably I shouldn't receive because I do not control the way it imports internal files.

Let me describe:

I have a library selectize.js. I import necessary scss file super simple, after I did yarn install I do

`@import "@selectize/selectize/dist/scss/selectize";` in my application.scss

But when I try to import bootstrap 5 styles

`@import "@selectize/selectize/dist/scss/selectize.bootstrap5";`

I receive an error

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "lib/bootstrap5/functions";
```

This import command is inside `@selectize/selectize/dist/scss/selectize.bootstrap5` that I've imported above and this file exists inside this node_modules folder.

So, it looks like when I compile

`sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules`

it takes a wrong relative path and use the path of my root app? what should I do?

What do I use:

Rails                           7.0.4.2

yarn                            1.22.19

sass                            1.53.0

@selectize/selectize          0.15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another `--load-path` as a workaround:

```bash
--load-path=node_modules/@selectize/selectize/dist
```

Add it in your `package.json` compile script:

```json
"build:css:compile": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --load-path=node_modules/@selectize/selectize/dist",
```

Fingers crossed, this doesn't clash with anything in your app, otherwise you'd need to compile `selectize` separately or use plain `css` files.

Comment: also https://tom-select.js.org/ exists for a reason.

Comment: it worked but why --load-path=node_modules is not enough? I thought if will load everything that is under node_modules?

Comment: when you add `--load-path` you can import things relative to that path. this file works: `./node_modules + @selectize/selectize/dist/scss/selectize` and this one doesn't: `./node_modules + lib/bootstrap5/functions`. add another load path to fix it `./node_modules/@selectize/selectize/dist + lib/bootstrap5/functions`

Comment: ah, thanks! now I see

Comment: @alex Getting the same issue with TomSelect...

Comment: @MonroeMann `yarn add tom-select` and `@import "tom-select/dist/scss/tom-select.bootstrap5";` compiles without errors for me. looking at the code everything looks nicely contained to `tom-select/dist/scss/` directory with proper relative imports. what's your error?